# killing nodejs-repl inferior process and restarting it

Tags: javascript, node.js, emacs, elisp

Below function sends the app.js buffer contents to the ****nodejs**** repl buffer which works. The only problem is when it is executed for the second time it does not start with a new nodejs process.

```
(defun execute_js_stuff ()
  (interactive)
    (progn
      (save-buffer)
       (let ((nodejs_project_dir (node_js_project_path
                (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)))))
    (if nodejs_project_dir
        (with-current-buffer (find-buffer-visiting (concat nodejs_project_dir "app.js"))
          (comint-simple-send (get-process "nodejs") (buffer-string)))))))
```

So added some code to delete the process buffer and then restart it again. But it does not work.i.e the nodejs process buffer is created but the contents of the app.js buffer is not sent to the nodejs buffer. Any ideas what might have gone wrong.

```
(defun execute_js_stuff ()
  (interactive)
    (progn
      (save-buffer)
       (let ((nodejs_project_dir (node_js_project_path
                (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)))))
    (if nodejs_project_dir
        (with-current-buffer (find-buffer-visiting (concat nodejs_project_dir "app.js"))
          (if (get-process "nodejs")
          (progn (delete-process (get-process "nodejs"))
             (kill-buffer "*nodejs*")))
          (nodejs-repl)
          (comint-simple-send (get-process "nodejs") (buffer-string)))))))
```

Comment: A REPL is meant to persist, not to be restarted every time you send a chunk of code to it; if you want your workflow to be "edit app.js, then spawn a Node process running it, play with it until done, kill the Node process, and repeat", you probably want to use [`M-x compile`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html) with a command like `node /path/to/app.js`, with `M-x kill-compilation` when you're done playing with the app. (Or, with what you have now, try moving the `(nodejs-repl)` call inside the IF's PROGN.)

Comment: Also, you don't need the PROGN after the INTERACTIVE call; a function body is wrapped in an implicit PROGN already, so it's just redundant and pokes the indentation over further than it needs to be. Speaking of indentation, you'd do well to `C-x h` (MARK-WHOLE-BUFFER) then `C-M-\` (INDENT-REGION) on the buffer containing this code; that'll reindent it according to the Emacs Lisp standard, which helps a lot in telling what's where -- for example, it makes instantly obvious the fact that you're launching a new Node REPL whether or not you killed an old one.